# How to filter by initial using a button and display it on another activity using SQLite in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am creating a visitor management system app in android studio. I have a SQLite database where I can store, add, delete and view records. I now want to use another Activity with letters A-Z as buttons to click on one such as the 'A Button' and it will take me to a new activity and display every user that has a name beginning with A.

I have searched for hours trying to find and figure it out but can not find anything.

Database Helper is here:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String USER_TABLE = "USER_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_SINGED_IN = "SINGED_IN";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_STAFF_VISITOR = "STAFF_VISITOR";    
    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "user.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_STAFF_VISITOR + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_SINGED_IN + " BOOL )";  
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public boolean addOne(UserModel userModel) {   
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();  
        cv.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, userModel.getName());
        cv.put(COLUMN_STAFF_VISITOR, userModel.getStaff_visitor());
        cv.put(COLUMN_SINGED_IN, userModel.isOnSite());  
        long insert = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, cv);
        if( insert == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public List<UserModel> getallUsers(){

        List<UserModel> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + USER_TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            //Go through the results (loop). Insert them into a return list to display.
            do{
                int userID = cursor.getInt(0);
                String userName = cursor.getString(1);
                String staffVisitor = cursor.getString(2);
                boolean signedIn = cursor.getInt(3) == 1? true: false;

                UserModel newUser = new UserModel(userID, userName, staffVisitor, signedIn);
                returnList.add(newUser);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else {
            //Fail - do not add to list.   
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return returnList;
    }

    public boolean deleteOne(UserModel userModel){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String queryString = " DELETE FROM " + USER_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = " + 
        userModel.getId();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursor.close();
            return  true;
        }
        else {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<UserModel> getSpecificUser(){

        List<UserModel> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + USER_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " = " + "[]";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            //Go through the results (loop). Insert them into a return list to display.
            do{
                int userID = cursor.getInt(0);
                String userName = cursor.getString(1);
                String staffVisitor = cursor.getString(2);
                boolean signedIn = cursor.getInt(3) == 1? true: false;

                UserModel newUser = new UserModel(userID, userName, staffVisitor, signedIn);
                returnList.add(newUser);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else {
            //Fail - do not add to list.
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

This is used with Admin screen to add, delete and view all records.

I need this database to now work with my staff selection screen. which is this:

```
public class Staff_Selection extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn_home;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staff_selection);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(Staff_Selection.this);

        btn_home = findViewById(R.id.home_4);
        Button a = findViewById(R.id.btnAv);
        a.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button b = findViewById(R.id.btnBv);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button c = findViewById(R.id.btnCv);
        c.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button d = findViewById(R.id.btnDv);
        d.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button e = findViewById(R.id.btnEv);
        e.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button f = findViewById(R.id.btnFv);
        f.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button g = findViewById(R.id.btnGv);
        g.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button h = findViewById(R.id.btnHv);
        h.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button i = findViewById(R.id.btnIv);
        i.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button j = findViewById(R.id.btnJv);
        j.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button k = findViewById(R.id.btnKv);
        k.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button l = findViewById(R.id.btnLv);
        l.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button m = findViewById(R.id.btnMv);
        m.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button n = findViewById(R.id.btnNv);
        n.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button o = findViewById(R.id.btnOv);
        o.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button p = findViewById(R.id.btnPv);
        p.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button q = findViewById(R.id.btnQv);
        q.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button r = findViewById(R.id.btnRv);
        r.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button s = findViewById(R.id.btnSv);
        s.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button t = findViewById(R.id.btnTv);
        t.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button u = findViewById(R.id.btnUv);
        u.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button v = findViewById(R.id.btnVv);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button w = findViewById(R.id.btnWv);
        w.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button x = findViewById(R.id.btnXv);
        x.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button y = findViewById(R.id.btnYv);
        y.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnZv);
        z.setOnClickListener(this);    
    
        btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivityHome();
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

    public void openActivityHome() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Initial_Screen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnAv:
                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(Staff_Selection.this);
                List<UserModel> allUsers = databaseHelper.getSpecificUser();

                ShowUsersonListView(databaseHelper);
                break;
            case R.id.btnBv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnCv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnDv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnEv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnFv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnGv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnHv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnIv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnJv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnKv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnLv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnMv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnNv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnOv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnPv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnQv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnRv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnSv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnTv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnUv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnVv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnWv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnXv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnYv:
                break;
            case R.id.btnZv:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    private void ShowUsersonListView(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper) {
    }
}
```

Then the buttons pressed on this screen should update or display a list view or list of results depending on the letter selected to this screen.

```
public class Name_Display_Staff extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn_home;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.name_display);
        btn_home = findViewById(R.id.home_1);
        btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivityHome();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivityHome() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Initial_Screen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Any ideas of help would be great, or even documentation or videos that could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider the following which is based upon your code BUT has quite a few changes.

- **MainActivity** is equivalent to your **Staff_Selection** (26 buttons for alphabet)and
- **Activity2** is equivalent to you **name_Display_Staff** (get the passed data)

MainActivity is pretty long and perhaps prone to maintenance issues. So much of MainActivity has been rewritten to handle the Buttons by dynamically adding them based upon a String[] holding the letters for the buttons.

A ListView of the selected Users has been added and clicking on a user in the list takes you to the 2nd activity Activity2 which is vert basic in that it just gets the UserModel and writes the details to the log.

- The listview utilises a CursorAdapter namely a SimpleCursorAdapter, which is designed for working with Cursors.

The Layout used by MainActivity is much simpler in that NO buttons are defined. For the example/demo/suggestion the layout used is :-

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

- i.e. just the 2 views a LinearLayout for the buttons and a ListView for the list of UserModels.
- Note this layout is just for demonstration.

The DatabaseHelper has been modified by **a)** Adding a class variable for the database (you don't really want to be opening and closing the database) as per :-

```
public static final String COLUMN_STAFF_VISITOR = "STAFF_VISITOR";
SQLiteDatabase db; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
```

and **b)** adding the following 2 methods

:-

```
//* ADDED *//
public UserModel getUserById(long id) {
    UserModel rv = null;
    Cursor csr = db.query(USER_TABLE,null,COLUMN_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = new UserModel(
                csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_STAFF_VISITOR)),
                csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SINGED_IN))>0
        );
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}

// ADDED //
public Cursor getUsersByFirstLetter(String firstLetter) {
    return db.query(USER_TABLE,
            new String[]{
                    COLUMN_ID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID,
                    COLUMN_USER_NAME,
                    COLUMN_STAFF_VISITOR,
                    COLUMN_SINGED_IN
            },
            COLUMN_USER_NAME + " LIKE ?",
            new String[]{firstLetter + "%"},
            null,null,COLUMN_USER_NAME + " ASC",null);
}
```

- **getUserById** allows just the ID to be passed from MainActivity to Activity2
- **getUserByFirstletter returns a Cursor based upon the rows as per the letter passed e.g. calling it using getUserByFirstLetter("A") gets all rows where the UserName starts with A (passsing "" gets all rows).

otherwise **DatabaseHelper** is as it was (you may want to consider changing it based upon the above method.)

**Activity2**

This is a very basic activity just designed to show the principle of getting the appropriate UserModel. It doesn't facilitate a return (e.g. DONE button to finich the Activity).

When invoked it just gets the UserModel from the database and writes details to the Log.

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    public final static String MYINTENET_USERID = "ACTIVITY2_USERID";
    UserModel um;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        um = getuserModel(this.getIntent().getLongExtra(MYINTENET_USERID,-1)); //<<<<<<<<<< gets the UserModel based upon the id passed via the Intent.
        Log.d("USERMODELINFO","User is " + um.getName() + " staff_visitor is " + um.getStaff_visitor() + " onsite = " + um.isOnSite() + " ID = " + um.getId());
    }

    private UserModel getuserModel(long id) {
        return databaseHelper.getUserById(id);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

As stated this is quite different:-

- the buttons are dynamical added to the otherwise empty LinearLayout with an id of **buttonlist** based upon the constant ALPHABET (note how $ has been added to show the flexibility). Attributes of the buttons are the minimum. However, the selected button, has it's background contrasting the other buttons.

  - in the demo not all buttons appear (something you'd need to change)
- A SimpleCursorAdapter is used for the ListView.
- I've added a method to add some data so there is something to display for the demo.

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public  static final String[] ALPHABET = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z,$"};
    private Button[] buttons = new Button[ALPHABET.length];
    LinearLayout buttonList;
    ListView userList;
    Cursor users;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    int buttonBckgrndNormal = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    int buttonBckgrndSelected = 0xFFFF0000;
    int buttonTextColour = 0xFF000000;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        forTestingAddSomeData();

        buttonList = this.findViewById(R.id.buttonlist);
        userList = this.findViewById(R.id.userlist);
        // Add buttons for Letters of the Alphabet
        for(int i = 0;i < ALPHABET.length;i++) {
            addAButton(i);
        }
        setOrResetCursorAdapter("");
    }

    //* Setup the List View */
    private void setOrResetCursorAdapter(String firstLetter) {
        users = databaseHelper.getUsersByFirstLetter(firstLetter);
        Toast.makeText(this,"retrieved " + users.getCount() + " rows from database.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    users,
                    new String[]{
                            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USER_NAME,
                            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STAFF_VISITOR},
                    new int[]{
                    android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}
                            ,0);
            userList.setAdapter(sca);
            userList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Activity2.MYINTENET_USERID,l);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(users);
        }
    }

    //* Add a button dynamically */
    private Button addAButton(int i) {
        buttons[i] = new Button(this);
        buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(buttonBckgrndNormal);
        buttons[i].setText(ALPHABET[i]);
        buttons[i].setTextColor(buttonTextColour);
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonReset();
                view.setBackgroundColor(buttonBckgrndSelected);
                setOrResetCursorAdapter(((Button)view).getText().toString());
            }
        });
        buttonList.addView(buttons[i]);
        return buttons[i];
    }

    /* Reset ALL buttons as not selected */
    private void buttonReset() {
        for(int i=0; i < buttonList.getChildCount();i++) {
            buttonList.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(buttonBckgrndNormal);
        }
    }

    private void forTestingAddSomeData() {
        UserModel[] umList = new UserModel[] {
                new UserModel(1,"Fred","Harriet",false),
                new UserModel(2,"Mary","Sarah",false),
                new UserModel(1,"Annabel","Zed",false),
                new UserModel(1,"Bob","Claire",true)
        };
        for(UserModel u: umList) {
            databaseHelper.addOne(u);
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

When started the App (on it's first run) is :-

[image]

Clicking **A** button and :-

Just shows the 1 row for **A**nnabel

[image]

Clicking **F** :-

[image]

Clicking Fred on the List :-

Takes you to Activity2 (empty display) and the Log includes :-

```
D/USERMODELINFO: User is Fred staff_visitor is Harriet onsite = false ID = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry fairly new to this and have been chucked in the deep.